# scale down makes table too difficult to read - kableExtra

Tags: latex, r-markdown, kable, kableextra

I'm trying to generate a report from rmarkdown and i have a couple of tables to print in the pdf file. I'm using `kable` and `kableExtra` package

This table is large in width due to some columns that contains text.
I'm using `scale_down` in `kable_styling` options but the table becomes too small in the pdf and i don't like it.

This is an example of my df:

```
df<-data.frame(A=c('This is a quite long text that doesn't fit','This also is a long text that',B=c('aaaa','bbbb'),C=c('aaaaa','ccccc'),D=c(10,20))


knitr::kable(df,
                               format='latex', booktabs = T,
                    caption = "capt")%>%
        kable_styling(latex_options = c("hold_position","scale_down"))
```

how it appears on pdf

[image]

I can't find a way to make the table a little bigger ( in height) while keeping the table inside the paper margin

Comment: Instead of scaling the table, you could use fixed with columns. If you add `keep_tex: true` to your header, you can replace the `l` columns with something like `p{4m}` or whatever fits. (or have a look at the `tabularx` package to determine the width automatically)

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, then the answer is to simply increase row separation, which is something that can be achieved with LaTeX code (using [\arraystretch](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Questions/How_do_I_change_column_or_row_separation_in_LaTeX_tables%3F)). To do this, you simply need to add something like `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}` (to double row separation) **above your code chunk**. For example (using something closely based on your code):

````
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}

```{r}
df<-data.frame(A=c("This is a quite long text that doesn't fit",
               "This also is a long text that doesn't fit because it is very, very long and boring"),
           B=c('aaaa','bbbb'),
           C=c('aaaaa','ccccc'),
           D=c(10,20))


knitr::kable(df,
         format='latex', 
         booktabs = T,
         caption = "capt") %>%
    kable_styling(latex_options = c("hold_position", "scale_down"))
```
````

produces this:

[image: Table with increased row separation]

instead of this:

[image: Table with increased normal separation]

Obviously, you can set row separation to whatever you want (e.g. `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{5}` for a huge one, or `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}` for a modest one).

Please note that any other tables below will keep doing this. So if t any point you want to return to the normal row separation, you will need to add `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}`