# Scale kable table to fit page width when changing page size

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, knitr, pdflatex

I'm unable to scale a table using `scale_down` option from `kableExtra` if previously I modify the page size.

EDIT: I've rewritten the markdown file to make it more reproducible as suggested:

````
---
title: "test"
documentclass: article
output: 
  pdf_document:
    fig_caption: yes
    keep_tex: true
    pandoc_args: --listings
    latex_engine: xelatex
header-includes: 
- \usepackage{float}
- \usepackage{graphicx}
- \usepackage{subfig}
- \usepackage{xcolor}
---
  
```{r setup, include=F}
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
library(tidyverse)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, warning = FALSE, include = T, results='hide')
```

\clearpage
\eject \pdfpagewidth=297mm \pdfpageheight=210mm
```{r test, fig.show='asis', results='asis'}
do.call(cbind.data.frame, rep(mtcars, 10)) %>%
  as.data.frame %>%
  head(n = 10) %>%
  kable(format = 'latex',  booktabs = TRUE,
        caption = 'mycaption') %>%
  # kableExtra::landscape() %>% 
  kable_styling(latex_options = c('hold_position', 'scale_down'))
```
````

Comment: Sounds a bit like an xy-problem. Do you just want the table on a landscape page?

Comment: ... and can you make a *compilable* [mre] which does not rely on files we don't have access to?

Comment: Ok, I guess now it is reproducible.

Comment: not really reproducible - it still includes files we don't have access to

Comment: You're right. I've removed the non-reproducible line. The output remains the same.

Comment: @PacoelCuqui look there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68472627/scale-down-makes-table-too-difficult-to-read-kableextra